# Breezejs: Two entity types with same name but different namespace

Tags: breeze

I have defined a client-side entity called 'EntityA' with namespace 'NamespaceA'.

It is for entities coming from a third-party webservice.

In our server-side business model we also have an entity called 'EntityA' but with namespace 'NamespaceB'.

When I call manager.createEntity('EntityA'), it creates an entity of 'NamespaceA'.

How can I specify that I want to create an EntityA of NamespaceB ?

Comment: You create two data contexts JS libraries for both namespaces then you can call `manager.createEntity('EntityA')` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

After some digging it seems:

- Adding a custom entity on the client side with the same name(and a different namespace) overwrite the existing one in the `_shortNameMap` array of the `MetadataStore`
- Both entities can be created using their name: `createEntity('MyEntity:#MyNameSpace')`
- But only the latest can be created using its shortName: `createEntity('MyEntity')`

So there are two solutions:

- Having a different shortName for the new one.
- Call `createEntity` with the name and not the shortName